# VSCode disable prettier formatting when committing files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find an answer for this anywhere and I'm literally ready to start pulling my hair out.  I don't know how it started, but very recently VSCode has been auto-formatting my code when it's committed to github.  At first I thought it was on file save, so I uninstalled prettier, set editor:formatOnSave and editor:formatOnType to false (both in the settings.json file and in the Preferences UI), but it still is formatting before save.  I discovered this in the git logs:

[image]

I literally have uninstalled every extension I can find that I thought would prevent formatting.  This is all I have installed now:

[image]

Does anyone know what might be happening, or where I can completely disable this?  Again, the formatting is preserved until I click the checkbox at the top of the Source Control panel to commit my code.  It then takes code formatted like this:

```
public String methodName(String param1, String param2, Integer param3) {
...
```

and formats it like this:

```
public String methodName(
  String param1,
  String param2,
  Integer param3
) {
...
```

I don't like this and I need it to stop.  Please help me make it stop.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Disable prettier for the workspace

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the delay, I finally had a chance to get back to this.  I found out the issue was that a previous extension had littered the .git/hooks directory inside my project with a bunch of scripts that weren't cleaned up on removal.  I removed everything except the .sample files and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

You can run VScode from command-line - cmd.exe with all extensions disabled to narrow it down is it any extension issue:

```
code --disable-extensions
```